# Hiding input field with css in an embeded form

Tags: css, forms, input, hide, field

Hello i am using machforms, and unfortunately it doenst have a setting to hide or disable fields. im trying to do it with css, since you need to embed the form using javacode or php into yourpage like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var __machform_url = 'domain/forms/embed.php?id=13200';
var __machform_height = 479;
</script>
<div id="mf_placeholder"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="domain/forms/js/jquery.ba-postmessage.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="domain/forms/js/machform_loader.js"></script>
```

This is the html i see is View Page code.

```
    <form id="form_13200" class="appnitro top_label" action="#main_body" data-highlightcolor="#FFF7C0" method="post"><div class="form_description"></div>
<ul>
<li id="li_1" class="#li_1 { display:none !important; } highlighted"><label class="description" for="element_1"></label><div><input id="element_1" class="element text medium" type="text" value="" name="element_1"></input></div></li>
<li id="li_buttons" class="buttons"></li></ul></form>
```

i put this in css

```
#li_1
{
display: none !important;
}
```

does not seem to work, could someone point me to a correct way of doing this. Thanks

Comment: Your class attribute is invalid, but this shouldn't make any difference to your code not working. I tried it in a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jaRAp/), and the code hides the input field as expected. What is happening differently in your case?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing your inline CSS wrong. The correct syntax is `<li class="foo" style="display: none;">bar</li>` hope this helps! So: `<li id="li_1" class="#li_1 highlighted" style="display: none;">`

Answer (score 0):

`class="#li_1 { display:none !important; } highlighted"` is invalid. You're mixing stylesheet syntax with class name values.